# Update HTML table data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have php file that get data from MYSQL database and return `JSON` array of data.
I call it with `ajax` and receive every second a `JSON` array data like below :

```
$.post("loader.php", {
    command: mydata,
}, function (json) {

    var ans=$.parseJSON(json); 
    redesigntbl(ans);

});
},1000);
```

in `redesigntbl` function I create table with a jquery plugin called [jquery Columns](http://jquery.michaeleisenbraun.com/columns)

```
function redesigntbl(arr){
    $('#master').columns({
        data:arr,
    });

    console.log("added table update");
}
//});
```

but it can design table just first time and in other time that I receive json data can't update data of table.

is any plugin for that or i can do that with some edit.

Comment: does it have any error in console?

Comment: try this plugin https://datatables.net/

Comment: no error ... but cant redesign table or update value of table .

Comment: @LalkrishnanSL can update the row from json ?

Comment: One question, one point: q: is your function redesigntbl(arr) getting called (or is 'added table update' showing in the console)? If not check your ajax request is returning correctly. Point: it's not clear from the jQuery Columns plugin that this allows you to update the data. As Lal krishnan suggests, the data tables plugin is pretty good and allows you to dynamically refresh the content.

Comment: Check what the AJAX call is returning. There is a good chance, that jQuery has already parsed it, so calling `parseJSON` is unnecessarily and just breaks things: `function (json) {redesigntbl(json);}`